# Left Join Only Returns If Matching

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have two tables (claim_pics & claiminfo) I am doing a query for a results page.

Its works well.. when there there is a match of the two tables claim_id ( claiminfo.claim_id = claim_pics.claim_id ).

However when there there is only one table with a claim_id, namely in claiminfo, and not a matching claim_id, all of the attributes of the row show up except the claim_id.

There is no claim_id, so if a user clicks an edit button, there is no claim_id to tell it where to go.

I need it present the $results of the claim_id regardless is there is a match or not. Any ideas or work arounds?

Thanks.

```
$query   = "SELECT * FROM claiminfo 
                          LEFT JOIN ( claim_pics ) 
                          ON ( claiminfo.claim_id = claim_pics.claim_id )  
            WHERE( userid='$userid' )   
            ORDER BY claiminfo.ts
            DESC LIMIT 200";
```

// Will only return

claim_ids that both pics and info match

```
                  $result = mysql_query( $query );

                  while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result ) ) { 


                                    $namelocation =      $row['namelocation'];
                                    $claimholder =   $row['claimholder'];
                                    $occasion =      $row['occasion'];
                                    $geotag =    $row['geotag'];
                                    $lat =   $row['lat'] ;
                                    $lng =   $row['lng'];
                                    $claim_id = $row['claim_id']; 
                                    $img = $row['location'];




                                     $html = " ... "
```

Comment: PLEASE DON'T SHOUT. The shift key exists because proper casing makes text easier to read, and SHOUTING is annoying.

Comment: I think this is because the * is picking up the clam_id of claim_pics table instead of your claiminfo table.

Comment: My bet is that your limit clause is showing what seems to be only `claiminfo.claim_id = claim_pics.claim_id` - try returning all the rows and see if you get NULLs on the right hand side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As comments have noted, it is likely that a null `claim_id` from the empty `claim_pics` row is blanking the `$row['claim_id']`. The easiest way to get around this is to explicitly select and alias the `claiminfo.claim_id`:

```
$query   = "SELECT *, claiminfo.claim_id AS id FROM claiminfo 
                          LEFT JOIN ( claim_pics ) 
                          ON ( claiminfo.claim_id = claim_pics.claim_id )  
            WHERE( userid='$userid' )   
            ORDER BY claiminfo.ts
            DESC LIMIT 200";
```

You can then reliably get the claim_id with the variable `$row['id']`.

In a more general note, this situation demonstrates why it is generally better [not to use SELECT *](https://stackoverflow.com/a/322216/628267).

Comment: Tried it, it didn't return anything. Is the syntax correct for multi-select, meaning the comma?

Comment: Oops, have to do the asterisk first when specifying rows. Fixed my answer.